# Qt Installation requirements: unmet dependencies

Tags: application-development, qt

im a linux beginner and used google & Co.
by installing the requirements ( http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux.html ) for Qt:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev
```

i get the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

i solved the problem by removing libcheese-gtk23, libcheese7 and libclutter-1.0-0, but killed my Linux with this (i could install and use Qt, but after rebooting, the gui was dead).

if i dont install build-essential and libgl1-mesa-dev the Qt tells me, "cannot find -lGL".

My system: Zenbook 303LN, i7-4500u with HD4000, NVIDIA Gforce 840M, 256GB SSD, 8GB RAM, 64bit Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks for help

Comment: @Fabby: no, it couldnt help me

Comment: What does `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` show?

Comment: When shell i use it?
if i use it with no other commands, it shows no output

Comment: That's good!  Which of the solutions in http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa did you try and did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Clutter is required to run the new GTK 3 desktop environments. Reinstall those libraries, and try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to force everything to upgrade, which will likely allow you to then install libgl without any further problems.

Comment: 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' makes no change. but i reinstalled my ubuntu 14.04.02. i fund another post, that its a problem of 14.04.02, and 14.04.01 would not show this...